# How do I specify language of tweet when using tweepy?

Tags: python, tweepy

I'm trying to get tweets only in English. But when I specify lang, the resulting data frame is empty. When I remove it, I get up to 1000 tweets.

```
number_of_tweets = 1000
tweets = []
time = []

for i in tweepy.Cursor(api.search_tweets, q = "Birdman", tweet_mode="extended", lang="English").items(number_of_tweets):
    tweets.append(i.full_text)
    time.append(i.created_at)
```

I only wanted the tweets that are in English but they all seem to be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/api.html#tweepy.API.search_tweets) states that it requires the language to be "given by an [ISO 639-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_639-1) code". You want your `lang` argument to be `"en"` instead of `"English"`.